# OpenCV and cv2 problem in jupyter notebook

Tags: opencv, anaconda, jupyter, modulenotfounderror

I already installed `opencv-python-4.5.3.56` in my Anaconda Prompt(Anaconda3) but when `import cv2` or `import OpenCV` in my JupyterNotebook get this errors:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenCV'

What is my mistake?

I have windows 10 and python3

Answer (score 0):

Try to run :

```
conda list
```

This is a list of package installed in your envs. If opencv is missing, try :

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Comment: opencv is not in package list and i run "conda install -c conda-forge opencv" but i get this error "The channel is not accessible or is invalid." and in the following this this one " channel name: pkgs/main
  channel url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  error code: 403"

Comment: try : 
pip install opencv-contrib-python in your anaconda env